# Passing results in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a function that has a list of lists, it multiplies the sum of the inner list with the outer list.
So far i can sum a list, i've made a function sumlist([1..n],X) that will return X = (result). But i cannot get another function to usefully work with that function, i've tried both is and = to no avail.

Comment: Please clarify. It's unclear what are "inner" and "outer" lists.

Comment: In Prolog you have predicates that describe relations, not functions (with one exception: arithmetic functions).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
prodsumlist([], 1).

prodsumlist([Head | Tail], Result) :-
    sumlist(Head, Sum_Of_Head),
    prodsumlist(Tail, ProdSum_Of_Tail),
    Result is Sum_Of_Head * ProdSum_Of_Tail.
```

where `sumlist/2` is a SWI-Prolog built-in.

Usage example:

```
?- prodsumlist([[1, 2], [3], [-4]], Result).
Result = -36.
```

Answer (score 1):

The part "it multiplies the sum of the inner list with the outer list" isn't really clear, but I believe you mean that, given a list `[L1,...,Ln]` of lists of numbers, you want to calculate `S1*..*Sn` where `Si` is the sum of the elements in `Li` (for each `i`).

I assume the existence of `plus` and `mult` with their obvious meaning (e.g. `plus(N,M,R)` holds precisely when `R` is equal to `N+M`). First we need predicate `sum` such that `sum(L,S)` holds if, and only if, `S` is the sum of the elements of `L`. If `L` is empty, `S` obviously must be `0`:

```
sum([],0).
```

If `L` is not empty but of the form `[N|L2]`, then we have that `S` must be `N` plus the sum `S2` of the elements in `L2`. In other words, we must have both `sum(L2,S2)` (to get S2 to be the sum of the elements of `L2`) and `plus(N,S2,S)`. That is:

```
sum([N|L2],S) :- sum(L2,S2), plus(N,S2,S).
```

In the same way you can figure out the predicate `p` you are looking for. We want that `p(L,R)` holds if, and only if, `R` is the product of `S1` through `Sn` where `L=[L1,...,Ln]` and `sum(Li,Si)` for all `i`. If `L` is empty, `R` must be `1`:

```
p([],1).
```

If `L` is not empty but of the form `[LL|L2]`, then we have that `R` must be the product of 'S', the sum of the elements of `LL`, and 'P', the product of the sums of the lists in `L2`. For `S` we have already have `sum(LL,S)`, so this gives us the following.

```
p([LL|L2],R) :- sum(LL,S), p(L2,P), mult(S,P,R).
```

One thing I would like to add is that it is probably not such a good idea to see these predicates as functions you might be used to from imperative or functional programming. It is not the case that `sumlist([1,..,n],X)` returns `X = (result)`; `(result)` is a value for `X` such that `sumlist([1,...,n],X)` is true. This requires a somewhat different mindset. Instead of thinking "How can I calculate X such that p(X) holds?" you must think "When does P(X) hold?" and use the answer ("Well, if q(X) or r(X)!") to make the clauses (`p(X) :- q(X)` and `p(X) :- r(X)`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewrite of [Kaarel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349896/passing-results-in-prolog/353572#353572) (that's the intention anyway!) but [tail-recursive](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/255/last_semester/last_semester/prolog_course/md5/md5_accumulators.html).

```
prodsumlist(List, Result) :-
    xprodsumlist(List,1,Result).

xprodsumlist([],R,R).

xprodsumlist([Head|Rest],Sofar,Result) :-
    sumlist(Head, Sum_Of_Head),
    NewSofar is Sofar * Sum_Of_Head,
    xprodsumlist(Rest, NewSofar, Result).
```